# How to show that upper triangular matrices form a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $A$ be the group of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries. Let

$$B = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}\mid ad \not=0\right\}.$$

1. Show that $B$ is closed under multiplication.
2. Show that $B$ is closed under inverse.
3. Write a matrix in each left coset of $B$ in $A$. Is the set of left cosets infinte or finite?

I know that $B$ is a subgroup of $A$ if 1 and 2 are true.
I also know that $1$ is asking to show that if $C$ and $D$ are $2\times 2$ matrices belonging to $B$ then I need to show $CD$ does also. I do not know how to start.

Comment: Do you know how to compute a matrix product or the inverse of a $2\times2 $ matrix?

Comment: @Arnaud yes I do

Comment: So write two them and compute the product!

Comment: And then write a general one and compute the inverse.

Comment: How can this question be a duplicate of the cited questions when neither of them mentions the coset issue?

Comment: The coset part is covered in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708473/cosets-of-2-times-2-upper-triangular-matrices

Answer (score 0):

Let $P = \begin{bmatrix} p&q\\&r\end{bmatrix}$
Let $S = \begin{bmatrix} s&t\\&u\end{bmatrix}$

If $B$ is closed then $PS$ is in $B.$

Is there any reason why $P,S$ would not represent all pairs of matrices in $B$?

From what you know of matrices can you find $P^{-1}$

Is $P^{-1}$ in $B$?

The left cosets of $B$ is a the trickiest part of the problem

For some $a\in A$ it has a linearly independent set of columnvectors.

The first column of $aB$ will be a scalar multiple of $a$  The second column could be just about anything.

Comment: Are the blanks in P and S zeros? I am having trouble defining two matrices that would belong to the subset B. Can I just choose any P and S with variables and then multiply them together to show that B is closed under multiplication?

Comment: The blanks are zeros.  $P, S$ are generic matrices in $B$ and the product of any $PS$ will produce a matrix in $B$